# How to check how much execution time is spent in different dlls

Tags: c#, .net, performance

In my project I have some code which has been deveoped in VBA and it calls functions from different C# DLLs. currently the performance of the code has been degraded and I am planning to check in which function/dll most of the execution time is spent.
Kindly let me if any tool is available to check the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One professional profiler, [RedGate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm) is most helpful.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of profilers for .NET, ANTS is by far my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

I have been satisfied with [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just run it under the IDE. While it's being slow, just pause it several times and each time look at the call stack. If a significant fraction of time is being spent in dlls, you will easily see the biggest ones, and you will see what they are doing and why. [This is an explanation of why it works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)